# Firebase phone auth sends unreadable verification SMS for chinese and japanese language

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are using the library `FirebaseUI/Phone`. And our ios app is supporting for multiple languages.

The auth UIs are correctly localized but sms message are sometimes unreadable when the app language is Chinese or Japanese. English works fine.

Does someone has a solution for it. (It seems like a bug of some particular sms sending server. )

[sms is readable from the number in the first picture and unreadable from the second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk7pp.png)

We tried to set the languageCode as the document says like
`Auth.auth().languageCode = "fr"` and `auth().useAppLanguage` and so on.
No change for japanese and chinese. 
As a result we have to set languageCode to `en` for all languages.

Comment: Here the same with Spanish (tried "es", "es-LA", etc). This is a big issue, changing to "en" our users can't understand any error.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested phone sign in with the web SDK. I set the language code to "zh-CN" and I got the SMS in Chinese. Make sure you are passing the correct language code for Chinese (simplified: zh-CN, traditional: zh-TW)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this issue in FirebaseUI for iOS and I wasn't able to. Just to clarify the docs; you should be either set the auth language directly (using `Auth.auth().languageCode = "fr"`) or via the app's current language (using `auth().useAppLanguage`) but not both.

Please try using `Auth.auth().languageCode = "zh-CN"` only to set the auth language to Chinese.

Comment: FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.auth?.languageCode = "zh-CN"

Comment: I've tested it just now but it's the same(not correctly encoded). If i use "en", it works fine.